# gksu firefox & password

Tags: password, gksu

I have a launcher with `gksu -u someuser firefox`
Why does this launcher require root password instead of the password of the currently logged-in user.
The password window has the following message:

```
"Enter YOUR password to run the application firefox as someuser"
```

NOTES:

1. On my system, I enforce root password for all sudo requests.
   In `/etc/sudoers`, I have `Defaults rootpw`
2. `someuser` has a `/usr/sbin/nologin` login shell

According to the gksu man page: "gksu is a frontend to su and gksudo is a frontend to sudo."
However, in the situation above, gksu is not using su but sudo as the backend -- root password is required (the message displayed in the password window is not appropriate in this case).
When forcing gksu to use su as the backend such as in `gksu -w -u someuser firefox`, the command fails.
This may be related to the fact that `someuser` has a `/usr/sbin/nologin` shell.

1. Why using sudo is the default behavior and even an absolute requirement in this situation?
2. Why does `gksu -u someuser` even run when sudo is the backend and `someuser` is not a member of the sudo group?
3. What is the underlying logic of all this -- as the gksu man page is not very detailed?
4. Very importantly, what are the security risks of running sudo versus su in this case?
5. Are there other alternatives for running firefox as a restricted user with a nologin shell?

Comment: "On my system, I enforce root password for all sudo requests." "Why does this launcher require root password.." Uh, what's your question? Why `gksu` has a strange message? File a bug, then.

Comment: From the command line, if I su someuser, normally I get prompted for someuser's password, not root's password or the password of the currently logged in user. Why would gksu behave differently?

Comment: because gksu and gksudo despite the names are both frontends of sudo, not su.

Comment: This is quite counter-intuitive. Does this mean that when I run "gksu -u someuser firefox", firefox is running with elevated privileges despite the fact that someuser is not even a member of the sudo group?

Comment: No. When you give `-u user`, Firefox is run as that user - it is always your privileges that are used (in this case, your privilege to run as another user). `gksu` can be configured to use `su` as a backend, but default behaviour is to use `sudo`.

Comment: I actually tried to run "gksu -w -u someuser firefox" but that command fails. My guess is that it is because someuser has a /usr/sbin/nologin shell. Is this the normal behavior and using sudo as the back-end in this situation an absolute requirement? It would be great if you could elaborate on the underlying logic as the man page is not very detailed on this.

Comment: Now that we have got to the actual question, can you edit your post to clarify it? We'll reopen it and then I'll post a proper answer.

Comment: I updated my post as requested on 2/26... Did you see it?

Comment: I didn't. Now I have nominated for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

**Because you "enforce root password for all `sudo` requests"**

`gksu` is for all intents and purposes a graphical `sudo`. I hope this clears up any confusion you may still have.

Note: Some answers are too simple to require a long, detailed answer. This is one of those.

Comment: I'm going to add the one to my list of canned comments...

Comment: @Fabby Feel free.